Como puedo invocar un metodo en javascript desde C# asp.net
Quiero llamar una funcion que esta en javascript al momento de hacer un click a un boton en asp.net C# ya que al hacer click obtengo unos valores y esos valores seran enviados a la funcion, pero como puedo enviarlo.
Ya provee con
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FirmarScript", script, true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "FirmarScript", "Firmar('"+ script+ "');", true);
Pero no me funciona.
Saludos.
